# How to connect remotely from Windows to a Vagrant instance?

Tags: networking, mac, cygwin, remote, vagrant

Is there a way to connect from my windows pc to a vagrant instance running on my mac which is on the same network?

Ideally I would like to use cygwin or something equivalent

Comment: What are you running on the Vagrant instance?  Also, what are you trying to connect with? ssh?  vnc?  Remote Desktop?  Etc?

Comment: @MMB Vagrant usually runs linux on the instance.

Comment: You still need to provide more details.  Over which protocols do you want to connect to?  For example, do you want to connect over ssh or SMB?

Comment: Hello, I managed to connect directly through my IDE (phpstorm) which syncs the directories over ssh